# Why am I getting "Error: Definition spark.skins.mobile:TextInputSkin could not be found." error?

Tags: apache-flex, text, air, adobe, skin

I'm using amxmlc to build a SWF from an MXML source code file. I'm passing -swf-version=13 to amxmlc.

In the MXML source, I have the following line:

```
<s:TextArea id="inputTextArea" width="100%" height="100" fontSize="28" borderColor="#000000" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" />
```

I get these errors when running the amxmlc command:

```
...App.mxml(428):  Error: Access of undefined property TextInputSkin.
    <s:TextArea id="inputTextArea" width="100%" height="100" fontSize="28" borderColor="#000000" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" />
...App.mxml(428):  Error: Definition spark.skins.mobile:TextInputSkin could not be found.
    <s:TextArea id="inputTextArea" width="100%" height="100" fontSize="28" borderColor="#000000" skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" />
```

Why am I getting these errors? I need to be able to use the spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin in order to have use of the soft keyboard on iOS devices.

Comment: Could you post the amxmlc command you're using, along with any changes you've made to the air-config.xml file?

Comment: Are you building a mobile project? The mobile skins are not available for desktop apps, I don't think

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that one of the Spark libraries is missing.